# Gradle 4.8+ breaks ivy publish with custom configurations

Tags: gradle, ivy

I've got a gradle file which is working in some ancient version of gradle but I want to upgrade to gradle 5.0.  Unfortunately its using ivy rather than maven to publish its jars.  I've cut it down to a simple test case.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something or its a bug or what.  I've attached the gradle below.  I'm running it

```
./gradlew wrapper && ./gradlew publish --info && cat build/publications/ivy/ivy.xml
```

- It works as expected with 4.7.  It publishes the main jar and the source jar and adds the dependencies.
- If I switch to 4.8 it breaks, it only publishes the source jar, main jar and dependencies are missing.
- If I switch to 4.8 and comment out the configurations bit it publishes the main jar and dependencies again.

Perhaps there's a new way of doing things but if so I've failed to find where its documented.  Here's the source build.gradle.

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'ivy-publish'
}   

sourceSets {
  testSupport {
    java {
      compileClasspath += main.output
      runtimeClasspath += main.output
    }
  }
  test {
    java {
      compileClasspath += testSupport.output
      runtimeClasspath += testSupport.output
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'com.ibm.icu', name: 'icu4j', version: '58.2'
  compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'
  compile group: 'io.swagger', name: 'swagger-parser', version: '1.0.32'
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
  from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

task testSupportJar(type: Jar) {
  from sourceSets.testSupport.output
  appendix "test-support"
}

task testSupportSourceJar(type: Jar) {
  from sourceSets.testSupport.java.srcDirs
  appendix "test-support-sources"
}
artifacts {
  archives sourceJar
  archives testSupportJar
  archives testSupportSourceJar
}
publishing {
  repositories {
    ivy {
      name = 'myRepo'
      url = "file://${buildDir}/repo"
      layout "pattern", {
        artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/jars/[artifact].[ext]"
        ivy "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivys/ivy-[revision].xml"
      }
    }
  }
  publications {
    ivy(IvyPublication) {
      organisation = 'com.example.com'
      // If you comment out the configurations below it will generate sensible ivy.xml
      configurations {
        "compile" {}
        "runtime" {}
      } 


      from components.java
      artifact(sourceJar) {
        type "source"
        extension "src.jar"
        conf "runtime"
      }
    }
  }
}

wrapper {
  // 4.7 works but 4.8+ doesn't.
  gradleVersion = '4.7'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh man I just figured it out.  Its the relative ordering of `from components.java` and the `configurations` element bits.  If `configurations` is first it seems to take precedence over `from components.java` and the latter is seemingly ignored.  If you put `from components.java` before `configurations` it works and you don't have to manually declare the configs it generates by default any more.

FFS gradle.

Comment: Ok, doing this still breaks dependencies.... so now transitive dependencies are no longer picked up :(

Comment: Ok, I fixed the "disappearing dependencies" issue heavily inspired by this link: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8707#issuecomment-471436862